# JDBC - How to get the column name (not the original column name)

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a query something like this which rename the column name animal to bird.

```
select animal as bird 
from table;
```

I want to retrieve the column name bird through Jdbc and not the column name animal. When I do

```
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,username,password);
Statement st = cn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
resultset.getmetadata().getcolumnName(int)
```

I get the original column name instead of the renamed column name. 
How can I get the renamed column name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two functions:

```
 ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName()
```

The name function will give you the actual column name of the CREATE TABLE statement.

and

```
 ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel()
```

The label function will give you the renamed column name.

So in your case you have to go for the getColumnLabel() function :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(int)`

> Gets the designated column's suggested title for use in printouts and
>   displays. The suggested title is usually specified by the SQL AS
>   clause. If a SQL AS is not specified, the value returned from
>   getColumnLabel will be the same as the value returned by the
>   getColumnName method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
resultset.getMetadata().getColumnLabel(int)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel(int)